# jquery multiple selectors, fade in and out

Tags: jquery, multiple-select-query

I have my click function

```
$("#productlink1").click(function() {
    $('#productstitle').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#productstitle').html('<h4>Corporate Promotions </h4>').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    $('#productscontent,#flexibility').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#corporate').fadeIn(1000);
        }); 

    remove();
    $(this).addClass('active');
return false;
});
```

So when i click the link, the title fades out then the new title fades in, all works okay

However the second piece of code, the fade in is appearing before the fade out, this line

```
$('#productscontent,#flexibility').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('#corporate').fadeIn(1000);
            });
```

However if i just have one element selected it works fine

```
$('#productscontent').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $('#corporate').fadeIn(1000);
                });
```

Is there an issue with multiple selectors?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML. My guess is that either `#productscontent` or `#flexibility` start off invisible, therefore the callback executes immediately.

Comment: Sorry didn't want to post too many lines of code, but yes #flexibility and #corporate both start of as display:none in css, and #productscontent is shown

Comment: Too much code in a question is better than too little ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XgtVw/

```
 $('#link').click(function() {
  $("#div1, #div2").each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#div3').fadeIn(1000);
    });
}); 
})
```

Comment: updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XgtVw/5/ it works fine until i need to re-hide elements now on show

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery `.fadeOut()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the
>   callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the
>   animation as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the suggestions, I couldn't seem to get the above to work,

essentially as the element is hidden, its fading in immediately, a "hacky" way around this for me was just adding a delay

```
$("#productlink1").click(function() {
    $('#productstitle').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#productstitle').html('<h4>Corporate Promotions </h4>').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    $('#productscontent,#flexibility').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#corporate').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
        }); 

    remove();
    $(this).addClass('active');
return false;
});
```

This stopped the fade in until the other elements had faded out, its not how i wanted to fix it but it works for now.

With the other answers the same was happening

Elements already hidden would fade 1st

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LAPaS/)**

Hope you have hidden the element `corporate` at first

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#corporate").hide();     // hiding corporate on document load
    $("#productlink1").click(function() {
        $('#productstitle').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('#productstitle').html('<h4>Corporate Promotions </h4>').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        $('#productscontent,#flexibility').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('#corporate').fadeIn(1000);
            }); 

        remove();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment this is the error on JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LAPaS/7/ hidden elements fade in before the fade out